# Issues compiling ldap - Berkeley DB major version in db.h... none

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, openldap

I'm trying to compile openldap on ubuntu, but my `/configure` get stuck on this:

```
checking for db.h... yes
checking for Berkeley DB major version in db.h... none
configure: error: Unknown Berkeley DB major version in db.h
```

here is my configure command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/openldap --enable-overlays=mod --enable-modules --enable-bdb --enable-accesslog --enable-auditlog --enable-collect --enable-memberof --enable-syncprov
```

I have bdb installed in

```
/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7
```

I tryed to apply [this](http://www.openldap.org/devel/gitweb.cgi?p=openldap.git;a=blobdiff;f=build/openldap.m4;h=bdcb4d6a5a12c17c4f9a2a6297fc8b771d907a35;hp=caf8fc2aa6642b3d2ffe02f56dd0a343d4be32f5;hb=f19f1c32496f3728c16c13b87d91a912e94bb7b2;hpb=b5da411e1e34a3fbaaa0321bdaa211c12cebb278) patch to `openldap.m4`

I really have no idea how to go ahead

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to compile OpenLDAP from sources instead of using the binary package which Ubuntu provides for you?

Comment: Actually for personal curiosity

Comment: Oh, that's perfect then, go on! I guess you have `libdb-dev` package installed?

Comment: Yes, it's installed.